# Uploading Mp4 or video files to new 'video' model for Google Speech to Text API

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

Is it possible (or will it be soon) to upload video files to Google Speech-to-Text API without transcoding them before-hand to audio files, and then encoding them to .flac or LINEAR16?

I've attempted all the combinations I can think of to get the new video model (currently in beta) to accept an mp4 video file, but can't make it happen.

Incidentally, I noticed the [Speech-to-Text API demo](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) **does successfully take-in mp4 files and produce a transcription**. Does that mean this feature is currently available, but the documentation isn't out yet? Or perhaps that it will be coming soon? Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.